# Keep getting session out with OIDC JS client and Identity server 4 Authorization flow with PKCE flow on Azure app services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, identityserver3

Using Identity server 4 with OIDC JS client in every 10 seconds the application reloads, in the network tabs I can see

[image]

The end session URL is always been canceled and application reload frequently

```
Request URL: https://falconidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/connect/endsession?id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjU1RDY5MTZFODVCOUNENTgwRjQ0RTMzNzREMjZFOUFCIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MTAzNzU0NjQsImV4cCI6MTYxMDM3NTc2NCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9mYWxjb25pZGVudGl0eXNlcnZlci5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldCIsImF1ZCI6IkZldGVfQmlyZF9VSSIsImlhdCI6MTYxMDM3NTQ2NCwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IlVDaUt3LXBBdi14aFVINFRZVXk1a1EiLCJzX2hhc2giOiI5clc3UUY5ZEtqRXdubE9lTWpRTTVBIiwic2lkIjoiQjYwNEJBNEU5MTEyOURCQjYzNTJFOEJDNDZFQUM5QkUiLCJzdWIiOiJlNDEzMTIwYS0yYWEzLTQzZTktYTQ1MC1lZWU2NzBjY2EzMjEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MTAzNzU0NTEsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.lmfq1ZJ2ukkrZ-FPjtCPaEsBYM0HXCAF496dNGMH0WP-SBFbbSllLSPGcavpruzzA0n-JQmkshtEqhyMvk5-c81dQLgjblrQ-X5QrzGoRd6fXDMnWwR0dlm2ZC2TcPOcBJXdaW1nfjLChxxrQljHMNLBr1tAmPfTfx0kaG7uvoXg1iY1aNmBsFUs4erdYs24Wd0JPtGzlHrGc3wyXk7aJNS77Ocu9SHUTL5XLsecOPMX0CVqeAX0ibRT6b-VuJ6u0egMKzR6yS8vCx4DNdHIScuX-zyMvisDePiCwqbN_K9VE0iwy2CmNfMKmioPX-aora7V1qZwCdj2-Lp-OSVVwg
```

[image]

Identity server client setting

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    ClientName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = CorsUris(configuration),
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = bool.Parse(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Client:AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser").Value),
                    IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 200,
                    RequireConsent = bool.Parse(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Client:RequireConsent").Value),
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = bool.Parse(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Client:UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh").Value),
                    RedirectUris = LocalRedirectUris(configuration),
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = LocalRedirectUris(configuration),
                    AllowedScopes = AllowedScopes(),
                    AllowOfflineAccess = bool.Parse(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Client:AllowOfflineAccess").Value),
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    RequireClientSecret = bool.Parse(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Client:RequireClientSecret").Value),
                    RequirePkce = bool.Parse(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Client:RequirePkce").Value),
                    //AllowRememberConsent = true
                },
```

OIDC client setting

```
openID = {
authority: 'https://falconidentityserver.azurewebsites.net',
client_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
silent_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:4200/assets/silent-renew.html',
response_type: 'code',
scope: 'openid profile email',
automaticSilentRenew: true
```

};

I don't know what I am missing and where is the issue. Can anyone help me with the this issue

I am doing silent reniew and it is working fine as you can see in the network tab.

OIDC usermanager logs

[image]

Comment: Error says "insecure request".  Some of your URLs are HTTPS (secure) and others HTTP (insecure).

Comment: Yeah, because I have the angular app running with SSL on localhost, while the Identity server is hosted on the Azure

Comment: But you are redirecting!!!

Comment: Sorry I am running angular app without SSL, Yes its keep redirect

Comment: Then why is authority https?

Comment: @jdweng Now everything is in HTTPS, but still facing the same issue

Comment: Try deleting the cookie.  The code may still  be using the old cookie before you recent edits.

Comment: No its the same issue, I used the private browser

Comment: What happens if you put URL into a browser?  Are you getting an error or just disconnected?  Wondering if you need to add a UserAgent header to specify the type of browser : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: I am redirected to the logout URL of the identity server. I am quite not sure when the session is expired and the user is the logout even though silent reniew is also working. Am  I missing some configuration in the identity server ?

Comment: I can see in the OIDC client logs, when the token expires the session also ends, however, the silent token review is working fine updated on the question

Comment: I'm wondering if you turned on Keep-Alive in client if it would keep the connection opened?

Comment: How can I do that in the client side? I am using Authorization code flow with PKCE

Comment: I as thinking the connection was closing before the server finished processing the request.  A Keep-Alive sends empty TCP messages while connection is idle to stop server from closing.  Need to do more research to see how to get access to the client.. I did find "Do not use ID tokens to gain access to an API." which may be the issue.  See : https://auth0.com/docs/tokens

Comment: This issue is only happening on Azure app services hosted, however in the local environment same code is working fine. There are no changes only the Authority on the ODIC client is changed

Comment: You are not comparing Apples to Apples when comparing results between local and remote unless you are installing the same version of server in both cases.  Token expiring I would think would occur just do to moving the same server code from one machine to another.  The connection is completing and the authorization is passing.  Unless the timeout in the server code is different for different authorization which is not the usual case.  See following : https://github.com/auth0/docs/blob/master/articles/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce.md

Comment: Well I am still not able to figure it out, what the difference between local and remote, In local it is working fine but not with remote server

Comment: Maybe the version of server code or version of Net/Core

Comment: Its exactly the same version, on local as well as in the Azure web apps here is the repo if you can help me what wrong https://github.com/anandjaisy/IdentityServer Falcon-Identity is the identity server project

Comment: Are they running on same machine?  With Windows 10 there is a kernel that is different which can lead to issues.

Comment: I am using MAC on the local machine and on the remote server it is windows

Comment: Is server a desktop/laptop or something else?

Comment: Remote server is the Microsoft azure, local is MAC OS laptop

Comment: Most likely there is a difference in the two MAC machines.  Are they same version of windows and have same updates?

Comment: I don't have two Apple MAC machine, on local development I am using Apple MAC, while on the remote it is Microsoft Azure Windows machine

Comment: Is version of json the same?  One way of debugging is using a sniffer like wireshark and fiddler and see where connection is closing which you would see in an TCP [FIN] message.  Comparing the working and non working sniffer results you can compare differences.

Comment: Well, I can see the connection are alive in the fiddler, updated the question with a fiddler screenshot. I am not sure, but I think the issue is with the Cookies, but exactly not sure. Now I am using LINUX on the azure app services, but still the same issue, now the sever is kestral

Comment: I think the issue is -  Single-signout (monitorSession: true) What does this do? -- After you login into your application (post redirect from IDP server, OIDC-Client JS will include the CheckSession endpoint in an iframe and OIDC library internally pings this iframe every 2 seconds (default) to verify that the idsrv.session cookie value matches with the value inside the applications id token, If they do not match, OIDC will raise user signed out event addUserSignedOut. But I am not sure how to solve

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was

Single-signout (monitorSession: true) What does this do? -- After you login into your application (post redirect from IDP server, OIDC-Client JS will include the CheckSession endpoint in an iframe and OIDC library internally pings this iframe every 2 seconds (default) to verify that the idsrv.session cookie value matches with the value inside the applications id token, If they do not match, OIDC will raise user signed out event addUserSignedOut. It is up to your application, how you want to handle when this even get raised from OIDC. Just because you enable single sign out, unless application handles, it will not take the user back to login page

After digging more from the below source

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/729

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1983

I need to add

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // we need to disable to allow iframe for authorize requests
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

Now the application working fine in **CHROME** but not in **SAFARI**.

I need to manage Upcoming SameSite Cookie Changes in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1#supporting-older-browsers

https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/saml2p/config-sp/samesitecookies/

https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/

Add the below class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
 
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
   public static class SameSiteCookiesServiceCollectionExtensions
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// -1 defines the unspecified value, which tells ASPNET Core to NOT
      /// send the SameSite attribute. With ASPNET Core 3.1 the
      /// <seealso cref="SameSiteMode" /> enum will have a definition for
      /// Unspecified.
      /// </summary>
      private const SameSiteMode Unspecified = (SameSiteMode) (-1);
 
      /// <summary>
      /// Configures a cookie policy to properly set the SameSite attribute
      /// for Browsers that handle unknown values as Strict. Ensure that you
      /// add the <seealso cref="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.CookiePolicyMiddleware" />
      /// into the pipeline before sending any cookies!
      /// </summary>
      /// <remarks>
      /// Minimum ASPNET Core Version required for this code:
      ///   - 2.1.14
      ///   - 2.2.8
      ///   - 3.0.1
      ///   - 3.1.0-preview1
      /// Starting with version 80 of Chrome (to be released in February 2020)
      /// cookies with NO SameSite attribute are treated as SameSite=Lax.
      /// In order to always get the cookies send they need to be set to
      /// SameSite=None. But since the current standard only defines Lax and
      /// Strict as valid values there are some browsers that treat invalid
      /// values as SameSite=Strict. We therefore need to check the browser
      /// and either send SameSite=None or prevent the sending of SameSite=None.
      /// Relevant links:
      /// - https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07#section-4.1
      /// - https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-00
      /// - https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site
      /// - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/
      /// - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181
      /// </remarks>
      /// <param name="services">The service collection to register <see cref="CookiePolicyOptions" /> into.</param>
      /// <returns>The modified <see cref="IServiceCollection" />.</returns>
      public static IServiceCollection ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies(this IServiceCollection services)
      {
         services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
         {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Unspecified;
            options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
               CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
            options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
               CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
         });
 
         return services;
      }

      private static void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
      {
         if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
         {
            var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

            if (DisallowsSameSiteNone(userAgent))
            {
               options.SameSite = Unspecified;
            }
         }
      }
 
      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the UserAgent is known to interpret an unknown value as Strict.
      /// For those the <see cref="CookieOptions.SameSite" /> property should be
      /// set to <see cref="Unspecified" />.
      /// </summary>
      /// <remarks>
      /// This code is taken from Microsoft:
      /// https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/
      /// </remarks>
      /// <param name="userAgent">The user agent string to check.</param>
      /// <returns>Whether the specified user agent (browser) accepts SameSite=None or not.</returns>
      private static bool DisallowsSameSiteNone(string userAgent)
      {
         // Cover all iOS based browsers here. This includes:
         //   - Safari on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
         //   - WkWebview on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
         //   - Chrome on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
         // All of which are broken by SameSite=None, because they use the
         // iOS networking stack.
         // Notes from Thinktecture:
         // Regarding https://caniuse.com/#search=samesite iOS versions lower
         // than 12 are not supporting SameSite at all. Starting with version 13
         // unknown values are NOT treated as strict anymore. Therefore we only
         // need to check version 12.
         if (userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12")
            || userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12"))
         {
            return true;
         }

         // Cover Mac OS X based browsers that use the Mac OS networking stack.
         // This includes:
         //   - Safari on Mac OS X.
         // This does not include:
         //   - Chrome on Mac OS X
         // because they do not use the Mac OS networking stack.
         // Notes from Thinktecture: 
         // Regarding https://caniuse.com/#search=samesite MacOS X versions lower
         // than 10.14 are not supporting SameSite at all. Starting with version
         // 10.15 unknown values are NOT treated as strict anymore. Therefore we
         // only need to check version 10.14.
         if (userAgent.Contains("Safari")
            && userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14")
            && userAgent.Contains("Version/"))
         {
            return true;
         }

         // Cover Chrome 50-69, because some versions are broken by SameSite=None
         // and none in this range require it.
         // Note: this covers some pre-Chromium Edge versions,
         // but pre-Chromium Edge does not require SameSite=None.
         // Notes from Thinktecture:
         // We can not validate this assumption, but we trust Microsofts
         // evaluation. And overall not sending a SameSite value equals to the same
         // behavior as SameSite=None for these old versions anyways.
         if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome/5") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6"))
         {
            return true;
         }

         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Configure and enable cookies

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Add this
   services.ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies();
}
 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
   // Add this before any other middleware that might write cookies
   app.UseCookiePolicy();

   // This will write cookies, so make sure it's after the cookie policy
   app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

After doing all the changes, still, I am facing issue in **SAFARI**

Comment: The second link show the UserAgent and the User agent may need to be set/modified.  It also could be the code is working on Windows but not an Apple machine.  The Apple Operating System and/or kernel may need an update.

Comment: The issue is that I have hosted the Identity server to remote and consuming it from local. So the domains are different that's why the cookies are not valid. But quite not sure how to fixe for safari

Comment: You need a windows credential on your apple machine.  See : https://answers.uillinois.edu/illinois/page.php?id=68546

Comment: This is totally not related to my issue

Comment: Are you login?  What credentials are being used for the login?  To get into the domain you need a login.

Comment: After doing the above changes as well it is not working for me, on safari any idea ?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-macos-ios